# Strict map with custom reading method or type with custom read instance

Tags: haskell, serialization, deserialization

So, it is not a problem but I would want an opinion what would be a better way. So I need to read data from a outside source (TCP), that comes basically in this format:

```
key: value
okey: enum
stuff: 0.12240
amazin: 1020
```

And I need to parse it into a Haskell accessible format, so the two solutions I thought about, were either to, parse that into a strict String to String map, or record syntax type declarations.

Initially I thought to make a type synonym for my String => String map, and make extractor functions like `amazin :: NiceSynonym -> Int`, and do the necessary treatment and parsing within the method, but that felt like, *sketchy* at the time? Then I thought an actual type declaration with record syntax, with a custom Read instance. That was a nightmare, because there is a lot of enums and keys with different types and etc. And it felt... disappointing. It simply wraps the arguments and creates reader functions, not much different from the original: `amazin :: TypeDeclaration -> Int`.

Now I'm kind of regretting not going with reader functions as I initially envisioned. So, anything else I'm forgetting to consider? Any pros and cons of either sides to take note on? Is one objectively better then the other?

P.S.: Some considerations that may make one or the other better:

- Once read I won't need to change it at all whatsoever, it's basically a status report
- No need to compare, add, etc., again just status report no point
- Not really a need for performance, I wont be reading hundreds a second  or anything

TL;DR: Given that input example, what's the best way to make into a Haskell-readable format? map, data constructor, dependent map...

Comment: This question is a bit vague (unclear what kind of functions (and their types) you wish to have for such a map). It looks like you want a map from keys to values where the type of value can depend on the key (i.e. a [dependant map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-map-0.2.4.0/docs/Data-Dependent-Map.html)); but unless you really need to guarantee your program doesn't error at runtime (which is somewhat futile if you're reading data over the internet anyways) this is probably overkill. What about `Map String Value` where `data Value = ValA A | ValB B | ValC C | .. `?

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are very valid in their own respects, but since I was making an API to interact with such protocol too, I preferred the record syntax so I could cover all the properties more easily. Also I wasn't really going to do any checking or treatment in the getter functions, and no matter how boring making the reader instance for my type might have seemed, I bet doing all the get functions manually would be worse. Parsing stuff manually is inherently boring, I guess I was just looking for a magical funcional one liner to make all the work for me.